# Concatenate columns with different lengths based on specific columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different txt files containing the same number of columns but different lengths, i.e,

file1.txt

```
1650,A,2428057182945480,0.33446294,0.102967925,-0.3460815
1650,A,2428057232445480,0.086256325,0.719756,0.45393208
1650,A,2428057281945480,-0.04051014,1.1011207,1.0462191
1650,B,2428301534869292,-1.6426647,0.8912665,-4.4452224
1650,B,2428301584369292,-1.6128372,1.1938016,-3.1242943
1650,B,2428301633869292,-3.6656017,1.328025,-1.8204107
1650,B,2428301683369292,-6.0336843,2.2516093,-1.7117537
1650,B,2428301732869292,-3.2778456,-0.43924874,-1.3911091
```

file2.txt

```
1650,A,2428057133445480,-1.2798505,-5.187936,-2.3116016
1650,A,2428057182945480,-3.3029509,-6.8231754,-4.011485
1650,A,2428057232445480,-2.876783,-8.365042,-7.171831
1650,A,2428057281945480,-2.2542906,-8.5661545,-8.153454
1650,A,2428057331445480,-3.2646437,-10.953174,-8.826224
1650,B,2428301485369292,6.3887777,-0.42347443,0.82480246
1650,B,2428301534869292,8.522012,-16.99614,9.446322
```

As can be observed that both files have different lengths in A and B. I want to concatenate both of them using pandas such that the result is as follows:

```
1650,A,2428057133445480,NaN,NaN,NaN,-1.2798505,-5.187936,-2.3116016
1650,A,2428057182945480,0.33446294,0.102967925,-0.3460815,-3.3029509,-6.8231754,-4.011485
1650,A,2428057232445480,0.086256325,0.719756,0.45393208,-2.876783,-8.365042,-7.171831
1650,A,2428057281945480,-0.04051014,1.1011207,1.0462191,-2.2542906,-8.5661545,-8.153454
1650,A,2428057331445480,NaN,NaN,NaN,-3.2646437,-10.953174,-8.826224
1650,B,2428301485369292,NaN,NaN,NaN,6.3887777,-0.42347443,0.82480246
1650,B,2428301534869292,8.522012,-16.99614,9.446322,-1.6426647,0.8912665,-4.4452224
1650,B,2428301584369292,-1.6128372,1.1938016,-3.1242943,NaN,NaN,NaN
1650,B,2428301633869292,-3.6656017,1.328025,-1.8204107,NaN,NaN,NaN
1650,B,2428301683369292,-6.0336843,2.2516093,-1.7117537,NaN,NaN,NaN
1650,B,2428301732869292,-3.2778456,-0.43924874,-1.3911091,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

Based on my understanding I can first generate the `dataframes` and then use `concatenate` like this

```
df1 = read_data('file1.txt')
df2 = read_data('file2.txt')
pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

Is this correct? If not, how to solve this problem?

Additionally, how to remove rows with `Nan` such that the result becomes

```
1650,A,2428057182945480,0.33446294,0.102967925,-0.3460815,-3.3029509,-6.8231754,-4.011485
1650,A,2428057232445480,0.086256325,0.719756,0.45393208,-2.876783,-8.365042,-7.171831
1650,A,2428057281945480,-0.04051014,1.1011207,1.0462191,-2.2542906,-8.5661545,-8.153454
1650,B,2428301534869292,8.522012,-16.99614,9.446322,-1.6426647,0.8912665,-4.4452224
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the column names so I am just putting dummy column names:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('untitled.txt') # this is the first txt with columns abcdef
df2 = pd.read_csv('untitled1.txt') # this is the second txt with columns abcghi
 
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['a','b','c']).dropna() # this gives what you want
```

Comment: The ['a','b','c'] values of df1 are replaced by df2. How to solve this issue?

Comment: a,b and c are the first 3 columns which are column in both your text files. You are using them as the key for the join. They will be the same in both text files for the row to exist.

Comment: I see. I misunderstand a, b, c as the last 3 columns.